# excel formula based on multiple conditions

Tags: excel, array-formulas

I am over searching for an answer now, so please assist me.

Excel

I am wanting to compare insurances based on the excess payable and have multiple scenarios where the excess changes and the bills paid changes; but within this is a second level 'type' of excess.

1. my bills come to 1000.00
2. my excess is 300.00
3. so my payable amount is 300.00 which leaves 700.00
4. however, of the 700.00 i only have to pay 10%

so the first part is 1000 minus 300 =700 x 10% = 70.00
However, in some cases I return a minus result, that does not count, so I created an IF statement
IF(1000 – 300 <0,0,1000-300) or as exactly in my spread sheet: =IF(B19-B21<0,0,B19-B21)

HOWEVER, in some cases if my bills come to 20,000.00 then 10% is 1970.00 but the max I would have to pay is 700.00.

So what I want to do, really, is calculate the 10% only if the result of 1000 minus 300 (or whatever) is within the range of 1 to 700.
Or another way is:
If the result of bills minus excess is 0 or a negative, then do not calculate the 10% and leave cell as Zero and the second condition is if the Bills minus Excess is 701 or more, then the cell should show 700.00

Ok. I think that is it and my first ever question on a site like this.

Thank you for any assistance.

Jamie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
=IF(B19-B21<0,0,IF((B19-B21)/10>700,700,(B19-B21)/10))
```

Comment: Thank you Jordan. Perfect.. I was kinda of heading that way... but I must admit my head was just not holding it together. So thank you for the reply. Have a great day :) :)

Comment: No problem; you can mark the answer as correct if you're satisfied it closes the question.